# How to find what exchanges SPY options are traded on?

Tags: options, options-exchanges

Searching for "SPY options" on Google gets me to either the [CBOE website](http://www.cboe.com/products/options-on-single-stocks-and-exchange-traded-products/options-on-exchange-traded-products/cboe-options-on-us-stock-index-based-etps/cboe-spdr-options-spy) or option chains websites like [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options/).

So I couldn't find an overview for all exchanges where SPY options are traded on. Is CBOE the only place? If not, where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Options Exchanges:

- BOX Exchange LLC, Boston, MA 02110
- Cboe Exchange Inc., Chicago, IL    60605
- Cboe BZX Options Exchange, Lenexa, KS 66214
- Cboe C2 Exchange, Chicago, IL 60605
- Cboe EDGX Options Exchange, Lenexa, KS 66214
- MIAX Options Exchange, Princeton, NJ 08540
- MIAX Emerald LLC,    Princeton, NJ 08540
- MIAX PEARL LLC, Princeton, NJ 08540
- Nasdaq BX    Options, New York, NY 10006
- Nasdaq GEMX, New York, NY 10004
- Nasdaq ISE,    New York, NY 10004
- Nasdaq MRX, New York, NY 10004
- Nasdaq Options Market, New York, NY 10006
- Nasdaq PHLX LLC, Philadelphia, PA 19103
- NYSE    American Options, New York, NY 10005
- NYSE Arca Options, Chicago, IL    60606

Source:
https://www.theocc.com/clearing/clearing-services/exchanges.jsp

Comment: This seems to be an exhaustive list of all options exchanges in the US. Given that SPY is the biggest ETF out there, I'd assume you can trade SPY derivatives everywhere, although what I'm looking for is an aggregator that clearly shows what instruments you can trade on what exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to obtain this data for SPY options or any other security. It involves an account with Interactive Brokers and [Trader Workstation](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=13868) installed locally. Steps:

1. Tap the "+" sing at the bottom of the screen
2. Select "Options Trading" from the layout library
3. Input "SPY" in the top-left input box
4. Click right on any option box, then "Financial Instrument Info", then "Details", and you will be redirected to the website below

[image: Trader Workstation Financial Instrument Info for SPY]

As you can see, SPY options can be traded on AMEX, BATS, BOX, CBOE, CBOE2, EDGX, EMERALD, GEMINI, ISE, MERCURY, MIAX, NASDAQBX, PEARL, PHLX and PSE.

And you can repeat this process for any other security with an options chain available to trade on Trader Workstation.